# Is there a way to maintain line breaks in pure markdown syntax when converting to html with Pandoc?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I'm currently using Pandoc to convert markdown code to html code. However, I've noticed that the line breaks are disappearing in the resulting html code. I'm executing the following command on the command line:

pandoc name_of_the_file.md -o name_of_the_file.html

I was wondering if there is an option available to preserve the line breaks when using pure markdown code.

Is there a way to preserve line breaks in pure markdown code without resorting to HTML tags like `<br>`? When I tried using `<br>`, it worked for the markdown code during conversion, but I prefer to find a solution that relies solely on markdown syntax.